# How do I download always the latest version of the programs when I use apt-get install [program]?

Tags: installation, apt, updates, eclipse, arduino

I tried to install the Eclipse IDE and arduino this way:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install arduino
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

But come the version Eclipse 3.8 and the Arduino IDE 1.0.3 and not the latest versions. Would specify which version of the program when I use apt-get install?

Comment: Related and possibly a duplicate: [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software) [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) may also help, at least for some software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command to apt-get update will refresh the package list with the latest available in the Ubuntu distro that you are using (I'm assuming your on 13.04 or 12.04.3 right?). If your are curious about what version apt-get will install, use the following:

sudo apt-cache show arduino

or;

sudo apt-cache show eclipse

It will produce the following output:

Package: eclipse
Priority: optional
Section: universe/devel
Installed-Size: 121
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers 
Original-Maintainer: Debian Orbital Alignment Team 
Architecture: all
Version: 3.8.1-1ubuntu1
Depends: eclipse-jdt (>= 3.8.1-1ubuntu1), eclipse-pde (>= 3.8.1-1ubuntu1)
Filename: pool/universe/e/eclipse/eclipse_3.8.1-1ubuntu1_all.deb
...

Trust this helps!

Comment: More information on check versions and other great things you can do with apt and dpkg can be found here: http://newbiedoc.sourceforge.net/tutorials/apt-get-intro/info.html.en

Comment: Ok my ubuntu is 13.04. Your answers helped me, but I think I'll download the Arduino IDE and eclipse direct from their website. Thanks to everyone for the responses.

Answer (score 2):

Packages in the official Ubuntu repositories are not always the current release versions from the developers. If the developers have their own repository you can always add that repository to your software sources and apt will pull the current version from there. Otherwise you will have to download the current version from the developer source and follow their directions for installing.

Answer (score 2):

That's the way you get the latest version of a package. What happens is that Eclipse 3.8 is the latest version available from the repos, in this case [universe](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/eclipse). Many software projects do not maintain packages for Ubuntu and you end up relying on voluntaries for the job. Eclipse is one of such cases and is usually lagging a good deal from the official release.

Since Eclipse itself provides automatic updates for its packages and interface you may opt for installing it manually.